How to find all analytic functions $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M(1+\sqrt{|z-i|}), \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$
I am trying to find all analytic functions in $\mathbb{C}$ such that:
$$ |f(z)| \leq M \left(1 + \sqrt{|z-i|} \right), \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C} $$
where $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
My first thought was that I could use the fact that analytic functions are not bound in $\mathbb{C}$ (except for the constant function), and to analyze the problem when $z$ approaches $i$, but I don't think I'm getting anywhere.
I know that the Cauchy-Riemann and Laplace equations hold for the partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$, where
$$ f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y), \quad z = x+iy$$
however I don't see how I can use them here!

Does the inequality have to hold for all $z\in\mathbb C$?

@Lieven Yes, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Show that $|f(z)| \le a + b\sqrt{|z|}$ for some constants $a, b > 0$ and conclude that $f$ is constant. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3491574/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326886/42969 .

FWIW, the constraint is equivalent to:
$$|f(x+iy)| \le M \left(1 + \sqrt[4]{x^2 + y^2 - 2y + 1} \right) $$
$$|f(re^{i\theta})| \le M \left(1 + \sqrt[4]{r^2 - 2r\sin\theta + 1} \right) $$

Essentially, this exercise repeats the proof of the Liouville theorem:
Note a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ satisfies the Cauchy formula
\begin{align}\tag{1}
f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(z_0)} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz,
\end{align}
where $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ is arbitrary, $r>0$, and $\partial B_r(z_0) = \{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| = r\}$.
Taking the absolut value on both sides of $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
|f^{(n)}(z_0)| &= \left| \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(z_0)} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz \right|\\
&\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int\limits_{\partial B_r(z_0)} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-z_0|^{n+1}} dz\\
&\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi } |\partial B_r(z_0)| \max_{z\in \partial B_r(z_0)} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-z_0|}\\
&= \frac{n!}{2\pi}2\pi r\frac{\max\limits_{z\in\partial B_r(z_0)} |f(z)|}{r^{n+1}}\\
&= \frac{n!}{r^n} \max\limits_{|z-z_0|=r} |f(z)|
\end{align}
Next, we use the inequality $|f(z)| \leq M(1+\sqrt{|z-i|})$: Let again $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary, then
\begin{align}
|z-i|\leq |z-z_0| + |z_0-i|
\end{align}
due to the triangle inequality, and since the square root is sub-additive, this means that
\begin{align}
|f(z)| &\leq M\left(1+\sqrt{|z-i|}\right)\\
&\leq M\left(1+\sqrt{|z-z_0|} + \sqrt{|z_0-i|}\right)
\end{align}
With what we got from $(1)$, this means
\begin{align}
|f^{(n)}(z_0)| &\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \frac{M\left(1+\sqrt{|z-z_0|} + \sqrt{|z_0-i|}\right)}{r^n}\\
& \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \frac{M\left(1+\sqrt{r} + \sqrt{|z_0-i|}\right)}{r^n}
\end{align}
Since $r>0$ was arbitrary, sending $r\rightarrow\infty$ for $n=1$ shows that $|f'(z_0)|=0$ for all $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$. In other words, $f$ is constant.
And the only constant functions $C\in\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $|C|\leq M(1+\sqrt{|z-i|})$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$  are the ones with $|C|\leq M$.

Use Cauchy's estimates based at $z=i$.
$|f^{(n)}(i)| \le {n! \over R^n} \max_{|z-i|=R} f(z) = {n! \over R^n}M(1+\sqrt{R})$. Since $R$ is arbitrary, we see that for $n \ge 1$ that $f^{n}(i) = 0$, and so $f$ is constant, bounded by $M$ (by setting $z=i$ in the upper bound).
